# Empty Body For Loop Linux Shell

Tags: linux, shell, loops, ubuntu

Hi I want to write and empty body loop. I just want the loop counter to increment so I want the cpu to stay busy without any IO operation. Here is what I have written but it gives me an error:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((  i = 0 ;  i <= 1000000;  i++  ))
do
done


root@ubuntu:~# ./forLoop
./forLoop: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./forLoop: line 4: `done'
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You must specify at least one command in a loop body.

The best command for such a purposes is a colon `:`, commonly used as a [no-op shell command](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#COLON0REF).

Comment: "It may be considered a synonym for the shell builtin true." - this makes this answer the same to the earlier one. ;)

Answer (score 4):

You could put a no op command inside the loop like `true` or `false` (do nothing successfully or unsuccessfully respectively).

This will be a tight loop and will burn CPU. Unless you want to warm up your computer on a cold morning, you can simply say `i=1000000` and have the same effect as the loop.

What is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: A NOP will not "burn CPU", it might show 100% usage but it will produce negligible heat output. You need to actually do work to warm up your processor.

Comment: Interesting point. Wouldn't incrementing the loop counter be work?

Comment: Probably not enough, the processor will be spending most of its time in the CMP/JNE instructions instead of the loop counter incrementation. But a few arithmetic instructions in the loop ought to do it (like a few multiplications/divisions).

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
let i=0 
while [[ $i -le 1000000 ]]; do
  let i++ 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sleep x` if you want to delay for x number of seconds.

Comment: This won't cause this loop to be a busy-wait loop.